# deselect tkinter canvas buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I have a button that is created by tkinter canvas button and i bind it so that when i press it it gives me a "sunken" effect and a value. However i want to give it another effect so that when i press it again, it goes back to normal which is "flat".

```
def press(canvas1, y):
    canvas1.configure(relief="sunken")
    print(y)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=50, height=20, borderwidth=1)
buttonBG1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
buttonTXT1 = canvas.create_text((25, 10), text="button", font=("Calibri", 8))
canvas.tag_bind(buttonBG1, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas, 100))
canvas.tag_bind(buttonTXT1, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas, 100))
```

Is their a way to that when i press the second time on the button, it is like the effect of releasing, but instead i want to press to release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle the value of the aspect of the button; here we do it with a closure that keept track of the state the state.

```
import tkinter as tk


def press(canvas1, y, toggle=('sunken', 'flat'), _turn=[0]):
    canvas1.configure(relief=toggle[_turn[0]])
    _turn[0] = (_turn[0] + 1) % 2
    print(y)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=50, height=20, borderwidth=1)
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    buttonBG1 = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
    buttonTXT1 = canvas.create_text((25, 10), text="button", font=("Calibri", 8))
    canvas.tag_bind(buttonBG1, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas, 100))
    canvas.tag_bind(buttonTXT1, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas, 100))

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i wanted

Comment: Although there is a problem in this code. If another button is added it takes the second argument of toggle initially until i press it again.

Comment: For more complicated designs, you could use a more sophisticated toggling mechanism that stores the state with the button. Encapsulating your buttons inside a class is one approach to do this.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the approaches. Thank you again!